# Is there a way to subscribe to multiple events at once in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, events, angularjs

Is there a way to pass several event names to `$on` method and to assign same callback to all of those events?

Basically, I am looking for something like `$scope.$on('event1 event2 event3', sameCallback);`. [Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24on) says that `eventName` is a string and doesn't mention allowing multiple event names there. Should I write my own convenience method just for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try just wrap on default function. I thinks is a good idea set events:

```
context.on = function(events, callback) {
 var events_arr = events.split(" ");

 angular.each(events_arr, function(event) {

    $scope.$on(event, callback);

 },this)

}
```

this is crude, but i think you know what i mean

Answer (score 1):

You can code it yourself, something like that...

```
[{event: "event1", callback:function(){}}, {event:'event2'}].forEach(function(item) {
    scope.$on(item.event, (item.callback || function(){}))
});
```